How much does it cost to generate a random number with Orao and Switchboard?
I know Orao and Switchboard are probably the most popular VRF solutions on Solana. I'm wondering how much does it cost (in USD or tokens) to generate a random number with each of the 2 solutions?
In addition, which token is used to pay the fee? Or the native SOL is used?

I am going to paste the response I got from Nik(Orao co-founder) when I shared this question with him

VRF fee is 0.001 SOL


with storage and PRE v0.4.0 it cost about 0.07 SOL to get randomness. as you can see most of that 0.07 SOL was spent on gas and Solana storage rent.


with the latest 0.4.0 upgrade the fee will be the same but 0.04 SOL will be returned automatically with fulfilment as storage is freed


switchboard will take lots of transactions and it will be very costly, not to mention the time it takes for fulfilment


regarding the last question on stack exchange, the contract has the option to pay with ORAO tokens, however this is live yet.


Thanks! Just to make sure, it takes around 0.031 SOL to generate a random number, right? Among these 0.031 SOL, 0.03 SOL is used for the storage rent, and Orao earns 0.001 SOL as fee. Is my understanding correct? If yes, then can I also free the storage after consuming the random number so that I can redeem the 0.03 SOL?

"nope, some of the storage is not freeable. what is possible to free up is returned to the account that requested the VRF"

The latest ORAO VRF for Solana is available on https://github.com/orao-network/solana-vrf
